# Detecting if a facebook user allowed or disallowed login

Tags: facebook

I am using FB's Javascript SDK using the login-button:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="onFBLogin();">
```

How can I detect within `onFBLogin()` if the user did log in successfully ? Currently it is called everytime, no matter what the user chooses.

Thanks,

Meir

Answer (score 3):

I think the first parameter passed into onFBLogin() is going to be either a response or a session object.  So check to see what the value of response or response.session is.

Also, have you played around with FBJS's login event handling?

If using [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    // user successfully logged in
  } else {
    // user cancelled login
  }
});
```

But since you're using an fb:login button, you can try to [subscribe to the login event](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  // do something with response.session
});
```

I haven't tried this myself via fb:login button, but hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Comment: +1 tried and it works. Rather than hardcode the login button, i put the button code into the 'else' section so as to prevent the button showing if logged in.